# Sending a variable to a different class

Tags: java, class, variables, bluej

I'm having trouble sending a variable balance and deposit to transfer from Driver to BankAccount, anyone have any advice? I'm using BlueJ.

Here is the driver class and method-

```
   import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Driver
{
    int choice;
    String number;
    String name;
    double deposit;
    double withdraw;
    double balance;
    //public Driver()
    public Driver()
    {
         String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("1. Deposit 2. Withdraw 3. Balance 4. Change name 5. Exit");
         int choice = Integer.parseInt(number);
         do
         {
         if( choice == 1)
         {
             String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much would you like to deposit?");
             deposit = Integer.parseInt(input);
             BankAccount b = new BankAccount();
             b.Deposit();
             Driver a = new Driver();
```

And here is the BankAccount program-

```
public class BankAccount
{
double balance = 400;
double deposit;
double withdraw;
double Interest = 1.05;
String name;
String accountNumber;

public double Deposit()
{
    //String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much would you like to deposit?");
    //deposit = Integer.parseInt(input);
    if (deposit < 10000)
    {
        balance = deposit + balance;

    }
    return balance;
}
```

Comment: You add a parameter to your deposit method e.g. b.Deposit(deposit); or create a constructor in bank account class.

Comment: Note that you don't send variables to classes; you send them to constructors or methods by defining parameters to accept the value from another variable.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have your depost method in `BankAccount` class as below

```
public double Deposit(double deposit){

...........

}
```

and your Drive class should be as

```
...
    b.Deposit(deposit);
...
```

method call